# PHP add days to current Date and Exclude holiday days

Tags: php, date, period

I'm trying to exclude a specific period from the date I'm going to print. I tried but without success.

The code I'm trying is this but not print anything and give me blank page:

```
$get_st_date = "2020-08-01";
$get_end_date = "2020-08-30";
$resultDelDate = strftime('%A %d %B', strtotime("+15 weekday"));
$get_period = new DatePeriod($get_st_date, $resultDelDate, $get_end_date);
echo $resultDelDate;
```

How can i do?
Thanks!

Comment: If you're going to work with Dates a lot, you should really give [Carbon](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/) a try. I usually don't recommend packages or plugins as solutions, which is why I wrote this suggestion as a comment, but this plugin has proved itself useful to me countless times in the past.

Comment: *but it doesn't work* what doesn't work?

Comment: not print the date and give me blank page :)

Comment: `var_dump($resultDelDate);` should tell you more about whats happening

Comment: Unfortunately nothing returns :(

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught Exception: DatePeriod::__construct(): This constructor accepts either (DateTimeInterface, DateInterval, int) OR (DateTimeInterface, DateInterval, DateTime) OR (string) as arguments - you can debug this [here](https://3v4l.org/20tmr)

Comment: What I would like to do is add the days to the current date, however, skipping a date range. How else can I do?